# Buttons not responding to hover or click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-grid

Using CSS grid, I have buttons and one div in a grid. That div is also a grid containing more buttons and divs. The buttons in the main grid work fine, but the buttons in the sub-grid won't respond to click or hover events. I have a CSS pseudo-selector to make the colors invert on the start button on hover, but it doesn't work, and I have a jQuery selector to make the strict mode button invert colors when you click on it, and invert back on a second click, but it also doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".header").html("<h1 class='text-center'>Simon</h1>");
  $(".count").html("—");
  $(".start").html("<i class='fas fa-play'></i>");
  $(".strict").html("Strict<br>Mode");

  var strict = false;

  $(".strict").click(function() {
    if (strict) {
      $(this).css("background", "#efefef");
      $(this).css("color", "#262626");
      strict = true;
    } else {
      $(this).css("background", "#262626");
      $(this).css("color", "#efefef");
      strict = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #262626;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  div.grid.main {
    display: grid;
    width: 90vh;
    height: 90vh;
    margin: 5vh auto;
    grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  div.grid.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: grid;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vw;
    margin: auto;
    grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

button {
  border: none;
}

.green {
  background: #15ff00;
  border: 1px solid #11cc00;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 3;
}

.green:hover {
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #15ff00;
  background: #11cc00;
  border: none;
}

.green:active {
  background: #15ff00;
  border: 1px solid #11cc00;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.red {
  background: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid #cc0000;
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 3 / 3;
}

.red:hover {
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #ff0000;
  background: #cc0000;
  border: none;
}

.red:active {
  background: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid #cc0000;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.yellow {
  background: #fffa00;
  border: 1px solid #ccc800;
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 1;
}

.yellow:hover {
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #fffa00;
  background: #ccc800;
  border: none;
}

.yellow:active {
  background: #fffa00;
  border: 1px solid #ccc800;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.blue {
  background: #006eff;
  border: 1px solid #0058cc;
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 3 / 4;
}

.blue:hover {
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #006eff;
  background: #0058cc;
  border: none;
}

.blue:active {
  background: #006eff;
  border: 1px solid #0058cc;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.menu {
  z-index: -1;
  background: #262626;
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2;
}

div.grid.menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 2fr 1fr / repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.header {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 3;
}

.count {
  background: #efefef;
  color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7vh;
  line-height: 8vh;
}

.start {
  background: #efefef;
  color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6vh;
  line-height: 6vh;
}

.start:hover {
  background: #262626;
  color: #efefef;
}

.strict {
  background: #efefef;
  color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4vh;
  line-height: 4vh;
}

h1 {
  color: #efefef;
  font-size: 8vh;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <title>Simon</title>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='grid main'>
    <button class='green'></button>
    <button class='red'></button>
    <button class='yellow'></button>
    <button class='blue'></button>
    <div class='grid menu'>
      <div class='header text-center'></div>
      <div class='count'></div>
      <button class='start'></button>
      <button class='strict'></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your issue is that `z-index: -1;` in the `.menu {` style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a layering problem..

Remove the `z-index` from `.menu`

```
.menu {
  /* z-index: -1; REMOVE THIS */
  background: #262626;
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS:**

The class `.menu` has a `z-index: -1;` what makes it not clickable because it is below all other elements.

**jQuery:**

The variable `strict` get set to `true` twice, so the click can only be executed once. *(if so desired, just leave it that way)*

---

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".header").html("<h1 class='text-center'>Simon</h1>");
  $(".count").html("—");
  $(".start").html("<i class='fas fa-play'></i>");
  $(".strict").html("Strict<br>Mode");

  var strict = false;

  $(".strict").click(function() {
    if (strict) {
      $(this).css("background", "#efefef");
      $(this).css("color", "#262626");
      strict = false;
    } else {
      $(this).css("background", "#262626");
      $(this).css("color", "#efefef");
      strict = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #262626;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  div.grid.main {
    display: grid;
    width: 90vh;
    height: 90vh;
    margin: 5vh auto;
    grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  div.grid.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: grid;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vw;
    margin: auto;
    grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

button {
  border: none;
}

.green {
  background: #15ff00;
  border: 1px solid #11cc00;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 3;
}

.green:hover {
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #15ff00;
  background: #11cc00;
  border: none;
}

.green:active {
  background: #15ff00;
  border: 1px solid #11cc00;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.red {
  background: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid #cc0000;
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 3 / 3;
}

.red:hover {
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #ff0000;
  background: #cc0000;
  border: none;
}

.red:active {
  background: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid #cc0000;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.yellow {
  background: #fffa00;
  border: 1px solid #ccc800;
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 1;
}

.yellow:hover {
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #fffa00;
  background: #ccc800;
  border: none;
}

.yellow:active {
  background: #fffa00;
  border: 1px solid #ccc800;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.blue {
  background: #006eff;
  border: 1px solid #0058cc;
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 3 / 4;
}

.blue:hover {
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #006eff;
  background: #0058cc;
  border: none;
}

.blue:active {
  background: #006eff;
  border: 1px solid #0058cc;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.menu {
  background: #262626;
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2;
}

div.grid.menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 2fr 1fr / repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.header {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 3;
}

.count {
  background: #efefef;
  color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7vh;
  line-height: 8vh;
}

.start {
  background: #efefef;
  color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6vh;
  line-height: 6vh;
}

.start:hover {
  background: #262626;
  color: #efefef;
}

.strict {
  background: #efefef;
  color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4vh;
  line-height: 4vh;
}

h1 {
  color: #efefef;
  font-size: 8vh;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <title>Simon</title>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='grid main'>
    <button class='green'></button>
    <button class='red'></button>
    <button class='yellow'></button>
    <button class='blue'></button>
    <div class='grid menu'>
      <div class='header text-center'></div>
      <div class='count'></div>
      <button class='start'></button>
      <button class='strict'></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

I hope that could help :)

Comment: Yeah thanks. After I got the buttons to respond, I realized that problem with strict. It's all good now.